# I cant use list view in android with json more than one result

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-studio

Hi every one I have a problem
i want to get data from site with json and show it in my android list view
but in my program i can only see the first result of json and dont
show me the all result of the json.
please help me.

this is my code

mainactivity code:

```
package com.example.delta.travel;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pd;
JSONParser jParser=new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> P;
JSONArray s=null;
private final String url="http://192.168.1.3/upload/travel.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    P = new ArrayList<>();
    new travel().execute();

}

class travel extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("login");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        List<NameValuePair> parms=new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject json=jParser.makeHTTPRequest(url,"GET");

        try {
            int t=json.getInt("t");
            if(t==1){
                s=json.getJSONArray("travel");
                for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                    JSONObject c=s.getJSONObject(i);
                    String companyname=c.getString("companyname");
                    String cod=c.getString("cod");
                    String bign=c.getString("bign");
                    String stop=c.getString("stop");
                    String date=c.getString("date");
                    String time=c.getString("time");
                    String price=c.getString("price");

                    HashMap<String,String>map=new HashMap<String,String>();
                    map.put("companyname",companyname);
                    map.put("cod",cod);
                    map.put("bign",bign);
                    map.put("stop",stop);
                    map.put("date",date);
                    map.put("time",time);
                    map.put("price",price);

                    P.add(map);

                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Data Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        pd.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, P, R.layout.item_list,
                        new String[]{"companyname", "cod", "bign", "stop", "date", "time", "price"},
                        new int[]{R.id.companyname, R.id.cod, R.id.bign, R.id.stop, R.id.date, R.id.time1, R.id.price});
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

and my json parser code:

```
package com.example.delta.travel;

import android.net.http.HttpResponseCache;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by delta on 5/28/2016.
 */
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is=null;
static JSONObject jObj=null;
static String json="";

// constructor
public JSONParser(){

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHTTPRequest(String urlString, String method) {

    if(method.equals("POST")){

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));
            String output;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(output);
            }
            conn.disconnect();
            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else if(method.equals("GET")){
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));
            String output;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(output);
            }
            conn.disconnect();
            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jObj;
}
}
```

and my php code:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","travels");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
$response=array();


$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from travel");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $temp=array();
    $temp["companyname"]=$row["companyname"];
    $temp["cod"]=$row["cod"];
    $temp["bign"]=$row["bign"];
    $temp["stop"]=$row["stop"];
    $temp["date"]=$row["date"];
    $temp["time"]=$row["time"];
    $temp["price"]=$row["price"];

    $response["travel"]=array();

    array_push($response["travel"],$temp);
    $response["t"]=1;
echo json_encode($response);

    }



}
else{

$response["t"]=0;
$response["message"]="Not Found";
echo json_encode($response);

}
?>
```

Comment: How did you debug your code? Did you check that PHP script prints the correct JSONObject that contains all the fields you need at once? Did you check that you adapter is created with a valid list of values? Try to find out where the data is lost.

Comment: my code is working and can get data from php and show it but it can show me only the first json result.

Comment: can you check ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> P;  size before setting the adapter?

Comment: im sorry but i dont know how check the size of the arraylist in this code ,can you help me?